# Distinguishing r- and l-value references as template arguments

Tags: c++, reference, variadic-templates

Let's consider the following example:

```
void f(int&& i)
{ }

template <typename ... X, typename ... Y>
void g(void(*p)(X&&..., Y&...))
{ }

int main()
{
    g(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with error

```
<source>:10:7: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(int&&)' to 'void (*)(int&)' [-fpermissive]
   10 |     g(f);
      |       ^
      |       |
      |       void (*)(int&&)
<source>:5:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void g(void (*)(X&& ..., Y& ...)) [with X = {}; Y = {int}]'
    5 | void g(void(*p)(X&&..., Y&...))
      |        ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Demo on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qjMjv5bG4).

Apparently on deducing the template arguments all the function arguments produce ordinary l-value references while the set of r-value references remains empty (contrasting my own expectations) – but why?

Side note: The problem that originally led to this question is solved by other means (recursive variadic template function producing a tuple) in the meanwhile, thus no XY-problem; asking out of curiosity – still would appreciate any other elegant solution which does *not* involve introducing tuples to the functions in question (`f` in above example).

Comment: if you change XY it appears to compile fine. https://godbolt.org/z/9qveMWs7Y

Comment: C++ never lets you split packs into several packs/non-packs, except in the single simple case of a single pack preceded by any number of non-pack items.

Comment: @appleapple It doesn't really work. One of the packs is always deduced as empty in this situation, apparently the first one.

Comment: @appleapple, you've basically just moved one `&` from the first to the second parameter.

Comment: @Enlico yes that's what I mean. sorry for not being clear. (I mean exchange `X&&` and `Y&` https://godbolt.org/z/7fqKxMM8q)

Comment: @appleapple, what I mean is that's coherent with the observation of the OP that the first pack stays empty, and the second pack is matched against the only argument.

Comment: @Enlico I'm not really sure I understand what you mean. But I mean from OPs "Apparently on deducing the template arguments all the function arguments produce ordinary l-value references". seems not the case.

Comment: Oh, I see. The OP is observing the compiler choses to let the r-value reference parameter empty, whereas you want to clarify that the compiler is leaving the first parameter empty.

Comment: @Enlico yes. :)

Comment: @appleapple Interesting observation, but if you now change `f` to accept an ordinary l-value reference [the issue arises again](https://godbolt.org/z/nzMc9G48x)... So my observation seems to be a red herring, apparently only the second (in general most likely: last) parameter pack seems to get filled – just as HolyBlackCat denoted already.

Comment: @appleapple is right here. Not that while ago clang/gcc would just say that the context of a function with two packs could not be deduced. Somewhat later something changed and now it just assumes, that all packs but the last one is of empty length. You can support either pattern by just introducing two function templates with the packs swapped - https://godbolt.org/z/ov7aT9KnE

Comment: @TheDreamsWind [Breaks](https://godbolt.org/z/6TxGM6Tdf) on `f` getting just minimally more complicated – even *if* that worked it would be undesirable as duplicating `g` which in reality is pretty complex... Apart from, all parameters getting into one single pack would make them indistinguishable from within the template function – which would be essential, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua correct. The real question to me is why it was agreed to support multi-pack function templates (instead of throwing a compile error), since i can't see how it can work anyway

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Agree only partially. The way the support was introduced indeed is meaningless – then better not allow at all. There are, though, a few corner cases where that *might* be meaningful. Original intention would have been accepting all input parameters as r-value references, all output parameters as l-value ones. As all r-values would precede the l-values the the two packs could have been distinguished one from another in a unique manner (my expectation; while then again compilation should fail if there existed multiple ways to distribute the parameters over the packs).

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I think it should be possible to provide arguments for the first template parameter pack explicitly and let the second one be deduced, i.e. `g<int>(f)` should be correct for `f(int&&)` as well as `f(int&&, int&)` and that is also how at least Clang handles it (though both GCC and MSVC complain).

Comment: @user17732522 interesting observation, but as far as i can see the same could be done with much simpler (and consistent) template: `template <typename X, typename ... Y> void g(void(*p)(X&&, Y&...))`. **Edit**: ok, ignore me. I can see it now that you can extend the arguments list further as needed (`g<int, int>` to accept `f(int&&, int&&, int&)`)

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting... Gives the impression that clang would pack all explicit parameters into first pack; GCC with all explicit parameters [works](https://godbolt.org/z/98q48zjqE), or seems so, at least – though that would render the entire approach much less valuable. If it is possible to distribute the parameters correctly that way, then why shouldn't it be possible implicitly???

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't think there is any deduction rule in the standard that considers interaction between the deduction of multiple template arguments like that. If not all pairs of corresponding function parameter/argument forms from which a template argument for a given template parameter is deduced agree on the template argument, deduction fails. (see https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#4.sentence-2) I think here the first function parameter pack is simply a non-deduced context (see https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.7).